# Find the real part of the complex number, with maximum amplitude, belonging to the region $A\cap B\cap C$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, solution-verification, contest-math

**Question:**

Let $A=\{z:|z+1|\le2+Re(z)\}, B=\{z:|z-1|\ge1\}, C=\{z:|\frac{z-1}{z+1}|\ge1\}$

Find the real part of the complex number, with maximum amplitude, belonging to the region $A\cap B\cap C$.

**My Attempt:**

B is a region outside or on the circle with centre $(1,0)$ and radius $1$.

C is y-axis or the region left to it.

A is parabola $y^2=2x+3$ or the region inside it.

Thus, the common portion is 'A' region to the left of y-axis or on it.

Complex Number with maximum amplitude, I think, is the numbers lying on negative x-axis i.e. $[-\frac32,0]$ as their amplitude is $\pi$. Here, I am assuming amplitude to mean the principal argument.

But **the answer given is $-1$.**

I think they are talking about some complex number with real part $-1$ and imaginary part I don't know. So, maybe this complex number lies in 2nd or 3rd quadrant. But why would it have maximum amplitude?

**Edit:**

I agree with Jean Marie's comment below that the set B playing no role here is off.

So, if I change the set B to $|z+1|$ then we do get $-1$ as the correct answer.

But with that, I am not getting the correct answer to the other linked problem to the same assignment.

> Find the number of points having integral coordinates in the region $A\cap B\cap C$.

With $|z-1|$, I am getting $6$, which matches with the answer key.

With $|z+1|$, I am getting $5$.

Comment: I have checked : all your sets are the right ones. Indeed, "amplitude" is, till a certain extend, synonymous to "argument". But an error could have been possible: your insstructor could have been using "amplitude" instead of "modulus", but even with this interpretation, it doesn't work. Besides, I have a question: why do you consider that $\pi$ is the maximum amplitude ? There are at least two conventions for the arguments: $(-\pi,\pi]$ or $[0,2 \pi)$.

Comment: A little strange that $B$ plays no role. Could the discrepancy come from this set ?

Comment: Another point to consider: all the negative real numbers have argument equal to $\pi$. So there is no single answer. Rather, it's a range: $-\frac{3}{2} \leq x < 0$. So maybe they chose $-1$ as a nice, round representative of that range... In any event, the fault lies in the assignment/answer sheet, IMO.

Comment: @JeanMarie we are told that principal argument is $(-\pi,\pi]$. So, I was thinking about $\pi$ to be the maximum argument. Also, set B plays part in another linked question in the assignment.

Comment: @JeanMarie I checked again. Even in the second question, set B has no role. So, I think you are right the discrepancy is occurring due to that.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have made an edit.

Comment: "With $|z-1|$, I am getting $6$, which matches with the answer key." I got $5$. It seems that you included $z=-1$ which has to be excluded.

Comment: @mathlove with $|z-1|$ case, shouldn't $(-1,0)$ be included?. In $|z+1|$ case, it should be excluded?

Comment: Since $C=\{z:|\frac{z-1}{z+1}|\ge1\}$, in both cases $z=-1$ has to be excluded. In both cases, I got the same $5$ points $(0,0),(0,1),(0,-1),(-1,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @mathlove isn't C giving y-axis and the region left to it?

Comment: Except $z=-1$. Note that $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ is not defined when $z=-1$ since $z+1$ is the denominator. Note that $|\frac{z-1}{z+1}|\ge 1$ is not equivalent to $|z-1|\ge |z+1|$.

Comment: @mathlove thankyou very much.